# Unable to access Username/Password page in wso2 identity server 5.10.0 in Kubernetes setup

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, wso2-identity-server

Have Configured OAuth2-OpenID Connect Single-Sign-On using WSO2 Identity Server-5.10.0 with my web application in Kubernetes setup.

While logging into web application, when i click on forgot username/password link in SSO login page, getting below error page.

[Error when we click on forgot username/password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhg9J.png)

Below are service and ingress rules am using:

```
**ingressrule.yaml**

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wso2is-ingress
  namespace: 
  annotations:
   
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - wso2is
    secretName: 
  rules:
  - host: wso2is
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: wso2is-service
          servicePort: 9443
    
**serivce.yaml**

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wso2is-service
  namespace : samplenamespace
  labels:
    deployment: wso2is
    app: wso2is
    pod: wso2is
spec:
  selector:
    deployment: wso2is
    app: wso2is
  ports:
  - name: servlet-http
    port: 9763
    targetPort: 9763
    protocol: TCP
  - name: servlet-https
    port: 9443
    targetPort: 9443
    protocol: TCP
```

```
deployment.toml

[identity.auth_framework.endpoint]
identity_server_service_url="https://$ref{server.hostname}:9443/services"

[event.default_listener.identity_mgt]
priority= "50"
enable = false
[event.default_listener.governance_identity_mgt]
priority= "95"
enable = true
[event.default_listener.governance_identity_store]
priority= "97"
enable = true

[authentication.authenticator.email_otp]
name = ""
enable= true
[authentication.authenticator.email_otp.parameters]
useEventHandlerBasedEmailSender = true


[output_adapter.email]
from_address= ""
username= ""
password= ""
hostname= ""
port= 
enable_start_tls= true
enable_authentication= true
signature = ""
```

if i curl -X GET https://wso2is:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/captcha?tenant-domain=carbon.super&captcha-type=ReCaptcha&recovery-type=password-recovery, getting below response :

`SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html   curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.`

- We are using below configuration in deployment.toml file and  All other APIs working with this config.
  `[transport.https.properties]`
  `proxyPort = 443`
- My application and wso2 IS are running as a pod inside same cluster.

**Attaching the logs from Identity Server when we click on forgot username/password link:**

`````
Error while performing the request method: GET on the resource: https://wso2is/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/captcha?tenant-domain=carbon.super&captcha-type=ReCaptcha&recovery-type=password-recovery com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.ApiClient.getAPIResponse(ApiClient.java:489)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:529)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.endpoint.util.client.api.ReCaptchaApi.getReCaptcha(ReCaptchaApi.java:105)
        at org.apache.jsp.password_002drecovery_jsp._jspService(password_002drecovery_jsp.java:197)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
        at org.apache.jsp.account_002drecovery_002drouter_jsp._jspService(account_002drecovery_002drouter_jsp.java:138)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:285)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
        at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:334)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:253)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
        ... 71 more
````
`````

Comment: The error trace says: `Connection Refused`. Which means, either the Service is not available or the Port that you are trying to invoke is not accessible. Can you do a simple cURL as `curl -X GET https://wso2is/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/captcha?tenant-domain=carbon.super&captcha-type=ReCaptcha&recovery-type=password-recovery` and verify whether it is able to reach the containers?

Comment: Hi @Athiththan , thanks for your response, after curling above request inside pod, am getting this response: **Failed to connect to wso2is port 443: Connection refused**

Comment: As suspected, the connection is getting refused. Can you check whether the services are up and running and the ports are open to being accessible? Also, can you update whether both Application and IS are running on Kubernetes? and whether you are using any Service configurations to expose the IS? Also, can you try the same cURL as (including the port): `curl -X GET https://wso2is:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/captcha?tenant-domain=carbon.super&captcha-type=ReCaptcha&recovery-type=password-recovery`

Comment: @Athiththan, please find the updated  post, after curling above API

Comment: Can you execute the cURL with `-k` to ignore the SSL. Command will be as: `curl -X GET https://wso2is:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/captcha?tenant-domain=carbon.super&captcha-type=ReCaptcha&recovery-type=password-recovery -k`. This is to check, whether the 9443 port is being accessible in your environment.

Comment: @Athiththan ,   have tried the curl with option -k also, got same response:   ``SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html``

Comment: `-k` shouldn't throw SSL certificate problem traces. Can you re-run the command again with `verbose` as well: `curl -X GET https://wso2is:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/captcha?tenant-domain=carbon.super&captcha-type=ReCaptcha&recovery-type=password-recovery -k -v`. Have you configured any Ingress or Services to expose the WSO2 IS service? Can you share those artifacts as well? I suspect, that the service is not reachable via 443 (either due to one of the service rules applied).

Comment: Hi @Athiththan, Getting same response for the above command also:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html.  we have given 9443 in ingress rules and proxy port 443 in deployment.toml file for both IS and APIM, Have Updated service and ingress rules above